# Can we write $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \frac{\sin k}{k}\leq a_\nu \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We known that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k}$$
converges. If $a_k\in\mathbb R$ and $a_k\leq a_\nu, \ \forall k\in\mathbb N,$ can we infer that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \frac{\sin k}{k}\leq a_\nu \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k}?$$

Comment: $\nu$ is whatever integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

For all $k \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$, take : $a_{k} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{it} \; \sin(k) \geq 0 \\[2mm] -1 & \text{if} \; \sin(k) < 0 \end{cases}$.

Then :

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} a_{k} \frac{\sin(k)}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\vert \sin(k) \vert}{k} = +\infty. $$

Since : $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}, \; a_{k} \leq 1$, the inequality :

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \frac{\sin(k)}{k} \leq 1 \times \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(k)}{k} $$

cannot hold because the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k \geq 1}{} \frac{\sin(k)}{k}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $a_k = \text{sign}(\sin(k))$, and $a_\nu = 1$, and the inequality is false because

$$\sum_{k\geq 1} a_k\frac{\sin(k)}{k} = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{|\sin(k)|}{k} = +\infty$$